# How to filter the objects with multiple values?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have the array of objects. when I require to filter the object by single vaue i am doing like this:

```
$scope.filteredByPhase = $filter('filter')($scope.allApps, {Phase:"All"});
$scope.allAppsBatch = $scope.filteredByPhase;
```

But as a option, I would like to filter the objects by 2 'Phase` values by "All" or "Home" in this case how to filter?

I tried like this:

```
$scope.filteredByPhase = $filter('filter')($scope.allApps, {Phase:("All" || "Home")});
$scope.allAppsBatch = $scope.filteredByPhase;
```

But not works.. any one guide me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AngularJS, you can use a function as an expression in the filter. In the function you can validate the condition and return Boolean value. All the `falsy` items are filtered out of the result. So you can do

```
$scope.filteredByPhase = $filter('filter')($scope.allApps, function (app) {
    if (app.Phase == "All" || app.Phase == "Home") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Read More : [**AngularJS Filter Documentation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Answer (score 0):

Use $filter passing an anonymous comparison function.

```
$scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, function (item) {
  return (item.Phase == "all") ? true : false;
});
```

Keep in mind that you may use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as well:

```
$scope.items = [{
  Phase: "home"
}, {
  Phase: "all"
}, {
  Phase: "all"
}, {
  Phase: "home"
}];
console.log($scope.items);
$scope.filteredItems = $scope.items.filter(function (item) {
  return (item.Phase == "all") ? true : false;
})
console.log($scope.filteredItems)
```

You may also trigger multiple filtering actions using chaining:

```
$scope.fi = $scope.i.filter(func1).filter(func2);
```